# Plot Outside Plot Region based on Normalized Device Coordinates in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a rectangle outside the plotting region. The rectangle should start at 10% of the entire device and end at 20%. In base R this can be done as follows

```r
## Example Data
dat <- data.frame(y = c("A", "B", "VeryVeryLoooongTitle"),
                  x = c(1:3))
## Plot
dotchart(x = dat$x, labels = dat$y)
opar <- par(xpd = NA)
rect(xleft = grconvertX(0.1, from = "ndc"),
     xright = grconvertX(0.2, from = "ndc"),
     ybottom = 0.5, ytop = 1.5, col = "blue")
par(opar)
```

[image: test]

I use `grconvertX()` to convert from normalized device coordinates (10% and 20%) to user coordinates (≈ 0.59 and 0.88).

I struggle to do something similar with `ggplot2` where I can specifying the coordinates as 10% and 20%.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(xmin = 0.59, xmax = 0.88,
            ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5,
            fill = "blue") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Is there any way to transform device coordinates with `ggplot2`? I saw that `grid::unit()` knows normalized parent coordinates but not normalized device coordinates (which takes into account long y-axis labels).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. You could simply draw a `grid::rectGrob` over your plot, but this has the downside that the end result is not a single ggplot object.

Perhaps the simplest way is to wrap a rectGrob using patchwork and use `inset_element` with `align_to = 'full'`

```
library(patchwork)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  inset_element(wrap_elements(full = rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = 'blue'))),
                left = 0.1, right = 0.2, 
                bottom = 0.65, top = 0.75, 
                align_to = 'full')

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Interesting function this `patchwork::insert_element()`. Do you know if it is possible to specify the x-coordinates in NPC units and the y-coordinates in user coordinates units?